# how to draw infinite amount of sprites?

Tags: java, arraylist, android-studio, sprite

i am a beginning programmer and I am making a flappy-bird kind of game in android studio. I am stuck at making missles coming in from the rightside of the screen. Any hints,tips,tricks on how to approach this problem? I thought myself of making a list of sprites and trying to loop this list an infinite amount of time, but i don't see how.

Kees

```
public Missles(GamePanel game, Bitmap bmp) {
    this.game = game;
    this.sprite = bmp;
    this.width = bmp.getWidth() / Sprite_Columns;
    this.height = bmp.getHeight() / Sprite_Rows;
    this.xposition = 1100;
}
private void update() {
    //Here we check whether the bitmap touches the bound or not.
    //if (xposition > game.getWidth() - width - xspeed) {
    //    xspeed = -5;
    //}
    //if (xposition + xspeed < 0) {
    //    xspeed = 5;
    // }
    xposition = xposition + xspeed;
    currentframe = (currentframe + 1) % Sprite_Columns;
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    update();
    // Here we cut our bitmap, such that we get the frames from left to right in the columns
    int smallrectX = currentframe * width;

    //choosing the second row of our sprite sheet, quite confusing y-axis though
    int smallrectY = height;

    // Making two rectangles, the frame of the spritesheet and
    // the position to put it in!
    Rect smallrect = new Rect(smallrectX, smallrectY, smallrectX + width, smallrectY + height);
    Rect position = new Rect(xposition, yposition, xposition + width, yposition + height);

    // making a drawing
    canvas.drawBitmap(sprite, smallrect, position, null);
}
```

}

and my gamepanel:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Sprite sprite;
private Missles missles;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private GamePanelThread thread;
private Bitmap bmp;
private Bitmap missle;
private List<Sprite> spriteslist = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
private Bitmap background;
private Bitmap scaledbmp;
private int xposition = 0;
private int xspeed = 1;

public GamePanel(Context context,int resource) {
    super(context);
    //TODO Auto generated constructor stub
    // unpacking sprites and missles
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
    missle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.angle_sprite);

    sprite = new Sprite(this,bmp);
    missles = new Missles(this,missle);

    // Making the surfaceholder and the thread for the gameloop
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    thread = new GamePanelThread(holder, this);

    // This statement improves the performance
    setFocusable(true);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    //Here i just creat the scaled background
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.cool_background);
    float scale = (float)background.getHeight()/(float)getHeight();
    int newWidth = Math.round(background.getWidth()/scale);
    int newHeight = Math.round(background.getHeight()/scale);
    scaledbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    createSprites();

    // starting the thread
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

private Sprite createSprite(int resouce) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resouce);
    return new Sprite(this, bmp);
}

private void createSprites() {
    spriteslist.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.angle_sprite));
    spriteslist.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.monster_girl_sprite));
    spriteslist.add(createSprite(R.mipmap.flyingwoman_sprite));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Drawing the background and sprites as it is a blackboard.
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp,0,0,null);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    for (Sprite sprite : spriteslist) {
        missles.onDraw(canvas);
    }
    missles.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                           int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // the purpose here is to tell the thread to shut down.
    boolean retry = false;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        sprite.up = true;
        return true;
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        sprite.up = false;
        return true;
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

}
```

and the gameloop:

```
public class GamePanelThread extends Thread {

private int FPS = 10;
private boolean running;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceholder;
private GamePanel game;

public GamePanelThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, GamePanel game){

    super();
    this.surfaceholder = surfaceholder;
    this.game = game;

}
public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    //tijd van gameloop
    long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
    while(running){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Canvas canvas = null;
    try {
        canvas = surfaceholder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized (surfaceholder)
        {
            game.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    } finally {
        if (canvas != null) {
            surfaceholder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.nanoTime()- startTime);//laatste deel is hoeveel seconden om 1 loop om te gaan;
    try{
        if(sleepTime>0) {
            this.sleep(sleepTime);
        } else {
            sleep(10);
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}


}
```

}

Comment: Learn object oriented programming. make all sprites their own objects with life, speed, direction. Then use ArrayLists to iterate through them to render them.

Comment: @micheal I know how to make the list and draw all the sprites in the list, but my main idea was to draw them one by one in some time interval. But when i get to the end of the list it doesn't restart the loop.

Kees

Comment: Where is your game loop? Prefably you have a thread running about 20-30(ticks) times a second, calculating everything happening, updating positions, calculating collisions. The render thread just reads the data from the game thread and draws on screen accordingly.

Comment: I have a game loop, should i post this as well?

Comment: yes. Then we can see how your gameloop interacts with your render thread.

Comment: i still think this is quite hard, don't seem to understand how to fix this....

Comment: Okay. You are using your render loop as your game loop. don't do that. have your render loop run independently, reading values out of the data objects in the game loop. Make a new thread that runs every 50 or 100 ms  to calculate new positions of things. Then in the render loop just read the positions and render the items accordingly. This way your render loop can have a nice fps(better than 10) whilst the game loop just runs along, not hindered by fps limitations.

Comment: i have managed to play the sprites at the same time, but it still fails. this method in the gamepanelclass keeps drawing all elements in the list at the same time, but that is not what i want :(


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Drawing the background and sprites as it is a blackboard.
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp, 0, 0, null);
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
        for (Missles missles : missleslist) {
            missles.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }

Comment: Your game loop needs to be a a seperate thread. Basically you have main app/render thread. This processes input and updates camera accordingly. This also posts future events to game thread which will process when it fires again on its next iteration. Youll end up with two threads and event queues

Comment: i am a noob and don't quite understand what you mean. can't I make a loop at the ondraw method such that we draw the first sprite in the list, wait 2 seconds then draw the next one etc....

Kees

Comment: Threads is the thing you will have to research and master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep track of an infinite number of sprites will require an infinite number amount of memory and take an infinite amount of time to draw. IE it won't work.

What you instead want, is to create some object, draw it on the screen and quietly recycle it once it goes off the screen.

The topic you need to look up is "object pool".

I would probably have a array of 5-10 missiles.  Each of them would have a bitmap, a location & a boolean 'isAlive' flag.  When I want to create a missile, I would look for a missile which isAlive==false and activate it.  I only need to update, draw & check collisions for the isAlive objects.  Once they move off the screen, set isAlive=false and they can be reused again.

This will probably be used for a lot of the stuff in an infinite runner game.

Comment: Keep in mind though you need a bitmap pool too. No use reloading the same bitmap over and over again for each sprite. All missiles can share the same bitmap.